# mod_rewrite rule 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from extension URL to extensionless one. For example, /contact should read the contents of /contact.php. I use the following rules to achieve this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

There is a file called test.php that has a variable called "id". I want to redirect read requests from /test/1 to test.php?id=1

I use the following to achieve this:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$            /test?id=$1
```

For some reason calling the test/1 file leads to a 500 internal server error. If I remove the rules to hide the php extension, it works again

Also how can I force a permanent redirect on the URL with extension? For example if someone ties to reach /contact.php should be redirected to /contact

Thanks

Comment: Is the second RewriteRule after the set of RewriteConditions and RewriteRule to add to direct request to PHP file?

Comment: sorry can't understant your question :(

Comment: Can you show the full htaccess file so we know where the two sets of rewrite rules you mention are positioned relative to each other?

Comment: It's the same in the question with the same sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# your existing rule (fixed)
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ /test.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you pls check your error.log and tell me what error you're getting.

Comment: Also see edited answer. I moved your `test.php` rule above rest of the rules.

Comment: the problem seems with the arrangement of the lines...now fixed..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is in my `htaccess`  ... Be sure to have `mod_rewrite` turned on in Apache...

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect .php requests to url without an extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
# This will remove the trailing slash unless it's a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```